# Deck vs decks for one powerpoint file

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

May I know if I want to refer to a pptx file (powerpoint file - of course there are multiple slides within), should I refer it as **deck** or **decks**? What if they are multiple pptx files?

> Recording and **decks** of the tech talk session, with Paul and John,
> are now available at this link.

Above sentence I want to refer as one pptx file, is the usage of **decks** correct?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of a PowerPoint presentation, [a "deck" is a collection of slides](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/slide-deck) (closely related to a "[deck of cards](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/deck_1?q=deck)" (def. 4), so if you're referring to a single .ppt(x) file, use "deck" (singular). If you're referring to a set of presentations (multiple .ppt(x) files), use "decks" (plural).

Comment: Note that in the specific example in the question, because the plural is used, the assumption is that Paul presented one slide **deck** and then John presented another slide **deck**. So, there was a single recording made of their joint session, which included the presentation of two slide **decks** in total.

Answer (score -2):

No, "deck" is not used in this way at all. You may be thinking of **a deck of cards**, which is a collection or stack of [playing cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_card).

In the tech world, PowerPoint files are commonly referred to as "slides" or "presentations." (Sometimes the files themselves are also called "PowerPoints" but I would not encourage this usage.) You could say "Recordings and **slides** from the talk session ... are now available."

Comment: At my tech workplace, the use of "deck" to mean a presentation is very common.  Quoting from an email that my director sent last week: "This morning we'll be reviewing [link to Google Slides presentation] and developing actions for each item. If you can find the time please review **the deck** beforehand."

Comment: See also [definition 5 of **deck**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deck).

Comment: @CanadianYankee Interesting. Can I ask what language region you're in? I'm sure I've never heard this before and I've seen a **LOT** of PPTs. I'm from the midwest (US) but do & have done a lot of international work.

Comment: I'm in Canada (Toronto), but I'm pretty sure I heard this when I worked at an Austin-based company as well.